# Does LSTM just mocking previous data?

Tags: lstm

I am trying to do a numerical time series prediction using `LSTM` but it seems that the `LSTM` just mocking previous data(Even when I use many-to-many prediction with different lengths) and when I plot the results that I get from `LSTM`, I a have very similar graph to real graph just with a time-delay!

[image]

The green graph is real and yellow graph is `LSTM` prediction(mocking).